# Is there a way to get the url of router.back in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, navigationbar

### Problem

I have an electron app with vue. As the user has no UI to navigate back I created a back button.
This works so far so good. But being logged in and on the **index page** the user shouldn't be able to navigate back any more. As he would navigate back to the login but would get redirected back to the index page. And this wouldn't make much sense. For that I want to **disable** the back button.

### Tested

I have added a global variable to get the previous route in my components. But somehow this gets messed up when clicking twice or more often. It looks like that:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  Vue.prototype.$prevRoute = from;

  return next();
});
```

I think it is because when navigating back the previous route changed to the route you were coming from. And not the history anymore.

There seems to be a github feature request to add the referrer but it was opened in 2016 and I am not sure if it will be again the same problem as above.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/883

#### In-component guards

I also tested `beforeRouteLeave` and `beforeRouteUpdate` but as the back-button is in my layout these methods are not called.

### Application-design

I am having a login-page with authentication. After that the user-information is stored in the local-storage and I am using a middleware concept for redirecting (https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/implementing-a-simple-middleware-with-vue-router/)

To go back I am using this method: `this.$router.back()`

### Expectation

My expected result would be to be able to check in the back-button-component if the back-route will be the login or if there the going-back-stack has only one value left. In that case I would disable my back-button.